# Map operator to create new Flux

Tags: java, project-reactor

I want to create new Flux from another flux. 
I know that using transformation operator in RxJava I can create new Observable isn't this the case in Flux?

I tried the following:

```
Flux f1 = Flux.just("one","two","three");
Flux f2 = f1.map(String::length);
```

But I get compilation error from my IDE.

The following complies just fine:

```
Flux f1 = Flux.just("one","two","three").map(String::length);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have and the full error message you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code:

```
Flux f1 = Flux.just("one","two","three");
Flux f2 = f1.map(object -> object.length());//compilation error
```

Since, you haven't specified the data type for `Flux` f1, the `map` operator is not able to resolve which type of data it is dealing with. Hence, it considers it as an `Object` type, which doesn't have the `length()` method.

Providing the data type should make it work.

```
Flux<String> f1
```

Where as, in `Flux f1 = Flux.just("one","two","three").map(String::length);`, the `map` operator knows that it is working on `Flux` of `String`, hence it's able to resolve the `length()` method.

Answer (score 1):

you should declare f1 as `Flux<String>`

Answer (score 0):

The method map(Function) in the type Flux is not applicable for the arguments (String::length)
you should do like this:

```
Flux<String> f1 = Flux.just("one", "two", "three");
Flux f2 = f1.map(String::length);
```